# Polymer paper-input element not rendering

Tags: polymer

Following is the code, with paper-input in body but it ceases to render. 
I was able to render paper-button though.

```
<script src="../components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="../components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
<body unresolved>
    <paper-input label="India"></paper-input>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you get any answer to this? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Unlike inputs using paper-input-decorator directly, paper-input does not work out of the box with the native form element. This is because the native form is not aware of shadow DOM and does not treat paper-input as a form element.

Use paper-input-decorator directly, or see ajax-form for a possible solution to submitting a paper-input.

Source: https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/paper-elements.html#paper-input

Comment: Yup. I solved it by importing core-input in conjunction with paper-input and it worked then.

Answer (score 2):

I know you have probably resolved your issue by now, hopefully but for others who may run into the same issue, try adding this inside your head tag:

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
```

It looks like you did not import **paper-input** correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and then found out I had paper-input v1.2

I reinstalled it and it changed to 2.x, then it started working.